# Testing old script with Laravel 7.x / php7.3.2 / mysql

Tags: laravel, debian

I am testing a script that is created with Laravel 3 years ago, but I am getting some errors...i want to know if is worth to edit these scripts or not.

System: Debian 9 stretch, mariadb, php7.3.2 (i've installed all modules what is needed for Laravel), Laravel is latest one (7.x)

After I uploaded files, I changed database to `/config/database.php`

I am new in Laravel, steps I followed:

1. `composer install`
2. Created default `.env` and changed db details & `chown -R www-data.www-data .env`
3. `php artisan key:generate`
4. `php artisan migrate`

After all, I got many errors. How can I fix this? Did I do something wrong? Thank you!

```
in UsersController.php line 74
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property 'casesLogs' of non-object', '/var/www/html/testserver/app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php', '74', array('user' => null, 'stats' => array())) in UsersController.php line 74
at UsersController->stats()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(UsersController), 'stats'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('stats', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(UsersController), 'stats') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: It seems that you try to access and `$object->casesLogs` but the object is not an object. When this append? While you run migration? Need more details please.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. This is the script in `UserController.php` 

public function stats() {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $stats = [];
        $stats['cases']['totalCasesOpened'] = $user->casesLogs->count();
//        $stats['cases']['totalMoneyWasted'] = $user->casesLogs->join('')count();
        return view('users.stats', compact('user', 'stats'));
    }

Comment: Also after migration, all tables were inserted in database, table for cases logs is `cases_logs`. Is anything related to this error? Thank you!

Comment: It's seems not related to migrations. I believe it's the line $user->casesLogs. $user is not defined, so maybe not logged in. Please try while logged in, or handle logged out case. If it does not help, try debug $user, and so auth()->user() that seems to be the issue here.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I cannot log in, there is no login page in `/public` folder. Should I do that with `php artisan`?

Comment: So that is your issue. You try to get the current logged in user. But there is not, so the relation property you are trying to access fails. Try by querying a user first like User::find(1) to get a safe user instance and test your code. But the issue is clearly from here: you try to use the current logged in user, but there is not. Use another way to get a user, or Authenticate him properly.

Comment: Hello, I tried what you said but every time is HTTP ERROR 500. There is a table users in the database, can this help? Thank you!

Comment: I need error 500 details to help